# SQLFilestream - Linq to SQL class or SqlConnection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sqlfilestream

I've been using LINQ-to-SQL class (.dbml) in my WPF/C# application to query and manage data saved in SQL server, and it has been working well. Recently we have an increasing need of saving files so I started to look at SQL Filestream. I'm very new to this so pardon me if the questions are vague or crazy... -

- Examples with SQLFilestream in C# that I can find seem to be mostly
  using SQLconnection rather than LINQ. Can someone provide or point me
  to a somehow complete example of saving and retrieving files with
  SQLFilestream using **LINQ**?
- In general, is there a reason/preference NOT to use LINQ to deal
  with SQLFilestream?
- What is the best practice for saving/retrieving files with
  SQLFilestream in WPF/C# applications?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Linq is not a saving mechanism, and never was; it is a *query* mechanism.  If you're confusing Linq with Linq to SQL, they're not the same thing.  Linq to SQL is an Object-Relational Mapper, and does have save capability.

Comment: Depends how you want to retrieve the data. If you just want to retrieve via the actual column, you can still do that as it is a `varbinary(max)` column. But you won't be able to use the `SqlFileStream` class with LINQ, you need fairly customized code for that